# How to maximize the profit for the given equation

Tags: calculus, optimization

It is a maximize profit question. Basically:

- There is a play which costs $180$
- Each attendee costs $0.4$
- Ticket price affects the overall attendance. When the ticket price is $5$, then there are $120$ attendees. If the ticket price is lowered by $0.1$, then there are $15$ more attendees.

How can I model this problem?

How can I maximize the profit? I believe it has something to do with derivatives, but I don't know how to approach it.

Comment: Just a little note: if you want to include dollar signs in your math environment, you can 'escape' them: e.g., `$\$45$` to get $\$45$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed cost of the play is $180$, variable cost is $0.4$ by attendee.

Total cost is the fixed cost plus the variable cost multiplied by the number of attendees:
$$c=180+0.4n$$

You can express the number of attendees as a function of ticket price:
$$n=120+15\times\frac{5-p}{0.1}$$

Total revenue is the ticket price multiplied by number of attendees:
$$r=pn$$

Profit is the total revenue minus the total cost:
$$
\begin{align}
 \pi&=r-c\\
 \pi&=pn-(180+0.4n)\\
 \pi&=pn-180-0.4n\\
 \pi&=(p-0.4)n-180\\
 \pi&=(p-0.4)\left(120+15\times\frac{5-p}{0.1}\right)-180\\
 \pi&=-150p^2+930p-528
\end{align}
$$

You get a quadratic function of profit depending on the ticket price, whose maximum you can easily get by calculating the coordinates of the vertex of the quadratic parabola described by the function:
$$
V\left(-\frac{b}{2a},\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a}\right)
$$

In this case, the profit reaches its maximum of:
$$\pi=\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a}=\frac{930^2-4(-150)(-528)}{4(-150)}=913.5$$
at the ticket price of:
$$p=-\frac{b}{2a}=-\frac{930}{2(-150)}=3.1$$

Comment: What is 'easy' calculation method of maximum profit after the last step?

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen For a quadratic function, you can calculate the coordinates of the vertex, which is the point at which the function reaches its minimum/maximum, and which can be calculated from a function in canonical form using a simple formula. I've updated my answer.